# How do I write an panel task bar in FLTK for use on Linux systems

Tags: linux, taskbar, fltk

I need to write a small application in C/C++ to implement a panel task bar like thing to display information along the top of a desktop window (specifically an xorg desktop on a Linux system). I need to avoid bloat and steep learning curves for the GUI programming.

My research is pointing me at GTK+/GTKmm or FLTK. It looks like FLTK is probably the simpler to get to grips with and the most likely to provide a small clean package with minimal dependencies. So I've based my research on FLTK so far.

I've been doing some reading and am struggling to find out how to write a basic program that will create a narrow undecorated window that covers the width of a monitor in such a way that maximising other applications would not obscure it. The FLTK tutorials I have found so far (including the FLTK documentation) only implement standard windows with borders that can be moved around the screen.

I'd like to start by writing a simple program in FLTK (or GTK+/GTKmm) that creates a 20 pixel deep bar across the with of the screen containing a "hello world" message. The bar's area would be reserved outside the area that other programs can access so that maximising another application would not hide the "hello world" message. I think this has something to do with a WM_STRUT_PARTIAL property but I can't find information about this in FLTK.

Doing this is partially to understand how to write a simple GUI program and partially to solve a specific need that I have.

I'm looking for any help/guidance to put me in the right direction to get started. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

starfry, it is not a trivial task I believe. The problem is that your desktop (say GNOME2/Metacity) reserved that space, and paints its panel in the area where you want your bar. -

If you really want your tray-bar applet to be based on [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org), the you would have to "embed" it in a (GNOME) applet. It was long ago when I did similar thing with SDL application, but I am afraid I forgot how to do it. The first thing that comes to my mind is to use somehow get the XID from the GNOME applet and somehow pass it to the FLTK part of it, and then let FLTK do the rest...

Sure, you may use another desktop, like [KDE](http://www.kde.org), or [i3](http://i3wm.org/) or [IceWM](http://www.icewm.org), they ALL have their own ways of dealing with the tray bar (there is no standard for it!) so, pardon my "French" - it is going to be a PITA to support all environments...

If I was on [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org), i would write the applet entirely using GNOME/GTK. Forget FLTK in that case. That is my recommendation. If you target KDE, then do it using KDE/QT libraries (Plasma widget would be what to look for).

However, if you still want to use FLTK, start with the [fltk::draw_into()](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/namespacefltk.html#af126be0f6e9553dc6d3dfa427365724f) function (it is probably called fl_draw_into() in FLTK 1.x), fltk::xid() and related functions.

Comment: I'm actually running OpenBox if that makes any difference.

Comment: In that case I suggest you first investigate how to write a tray-bar (if possible at all) for OpenBox. I can't help with that I am afraid. :(